# -C# Label & Literal not displaying value

Tags: c#, asp.net, save, edit

I have a profile that allows users to display, edit, save.

The save and edit works ok.

However, the display is not working properly.

I tried changing labels to literals but they don't either.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindGenderDropDownList();
            //this.BindTimeZonesDropDownList();
            //this.BindCulturesDropDownList();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Membership.GetUser().UserName))
            {
                Profile = MyProfile.GetProfile(Membership.GetUser().UserName);
                this.DisplayProfile();
            }
        }


    }

    protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DisplayProfile();
    }

    protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EditProfile();
    }

    protected void btnCancelDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResetElements();
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveProfile();
    }

    protected void btnCancelEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResetElements();
    }

    private void DisplayProfile()
    {




            this.SetElementsForDisplaying();
            litfullname.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName;


    }

    private void EditProfile()
    {
        this.SetElementsForEditing();



        if (Profile.ProfileDetail == null)
        {
            txtfname.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName;
            txtcardno.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardNo;
            ddlcardcolor.SelectedValue = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardColour;
            txtcardexp.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardExpiryDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
            ddlrace.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Race;
            ddlreligion.SelectedValue = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Religion;
            txtaddress1.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address1;
            txtaddress2.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address2;
            txtaddress3.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address3;
            txtpostcode.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Postcode;
            ddldistrict.SelectedValue = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.District;
            txtphoneoffice.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.OfficePhone;
            txtphonehome.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.HomePhone;
            txtphonecell.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.MobilePhone;
            txtemail.Text = this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Email;
        }



    }
```

Save profile. This is working properly.

```
    private void SaveProfile()
    {

        if (Profile.ProfileDetail == null)
        {

            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.FullName = txtfname.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardNo = txtcardno.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardColour = ddlcardcolor.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.IdentityCardExpiryDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtcardexp.Text, "dd MMMM yyyy", null);
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Race = ddlrace.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.Religion = ddlreligion.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address1 = txtaddress1.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address2 = txtaddress2.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Address3 = txtaddress3.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Postcode = txtpostcode.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.District = ddldistrict.SelectedValue;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.OfficePhone = txtphoneoffice.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.HomePhone = txtphonehome.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.MobilePhone = txtphonecell.Text;
            this.Profile.ProfileDetail.ContactInformation.Email = txtemail.Text;

        }



        this.Profile.Save();

       this.ResetElements();

    }
```

To display, which doesn't work properly

```
    private void SetElementsForDisplaying()
    {


        pnlDisplayValues.Visible = true;
        pnlSetValues.Visible = false; 
        litUserTitle.Visible = false;
        litUserTitle.Text = string.Format("Display profile for {0}", this.Profile.UserName);

    }
```

Edit profile. Working properly
        private void SetElementsForEditing()
        {

```
        pnlDisplayValues.Visible = false;
        pnlSetValues.Visible = true;
        litUserTitle.Visible = true;
        litUserTitle.Text = string.Format("Edit profile for {0}", this.Profile.UserName);
    }

    private void ResetElements()
    {

        pnlSetValues.Visible = false;
        pnlDisplayValues.Visible = true;
        litUserTitle.Visible = true;

    }
```

Comment: explain what you mean by `not working properly`?

Comment: The labels/ literals are not showing the data. Strange, because when I clicked edit. The data are still there. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void SetElementsForDisplaying()
    {
        pnlDisplayValues.Visible = true;
        pnlSetValues.Visible = false; 
        litUserTitle.Visible = true; // set this as visible 
        litUserTitle.Text = string.Format("Display profile for {0}", this.Profile.UserName);

    }
```

And in your `pnlDisplayValues` panel add the literals you want and set the values in the `DisplayProfile()` method

Comment: Didn't work. 
It displayed the title 
' Display profile for {0} ', this.profile.UserName;

Comment: you only set `litfullname.Text` in `DisplayProfile` what else you need to display?

Comment: The rest of the form. I think I got it*. Adding the rest of the literals now. \o Thanks :'D